# Text not displaying in right order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm trying to get JSON data to display in a paragraph, but have a divider between data taken on different dates.

```
function getAllLogs(emId) {
    $.getJSON('datafile.json', function(data) {
        $("#" + emId).html("All logs:<br>");
        var firstDateDisplayed = false;
        $.each(data, function(index, value) {
            //Only displays dates once, then all log sheets for that date
            if (firstDateDisplayed === false ||
                data[index-1].log_sheet.time !== value.log_sheet.time) {

                $("#" + emId).append("<br>----------------<br>");
                //Formats and appends date to a paragraph
                getLogDate(emId, index);
                firstDateDisplayed = true;
            }

            //Formats and appends time to a paragraph
            getLogTime(emId, index);
            //Formats and appends all data to a paragraph
            getLogData(emId, index);
        });
    });
}
```

What I want:

```
All logs:
----------------
Date 1
Time 1
Data 1
Time 2
Data 2
Time 3
Data 3
----------------
Date 2
Time 4
Data 4
Time 5
Data 5
```

What I get:

```
----------------

----------------        
Date 1
Time 1
Data 1
Time 2
Data 2
Time 3
Data 3
Date 2
Time 4
Data 4
Time 5
Data 5
```

Example JSON data:

```
[
    {
        "log_sheet": {
            "data":"4",
            "date":"2012-07-27T00:00:00-06:00",
            "time":"2000-01-01T02:15:00Z",
            "more_data":"7"
        }
    },
    {    
        "log_sheet": {
            "data":"8,
            "date":"2012-07-27T00:00:00-06:00",
            "time":"2000-01-01T07:30:00Z",
            "more_data":"3"
        }
    }
]
```

How do I fix this? My dates display correctly, but why don't the dividers?

getLogTime function:

```
//Gets, formats and displays the time for the current log sheet in the 
//header of a collapsible menu or paragraph
function getLogTime(emId, logNum) {
    //Accesses the JSON file
$.getJSON('datafile.json', function(data) {
    //Takes only the part of the string that corresponds to time
    var time = data[logNum].log_sheet.measured_at_time.substring(11,16);
    //Formats time to 12 hour clock according to the hour
    switch (time.substring(0, 2))
        {
    case "00":
        //Changes 00 to 12 and adds am
        time = time.replace(/00/, "12") + " am";
        break;
    case "01":
    case "02":
    case "03":
    case "04":
    case "05":
    case "06":
    case "07":
    case "08":
    case "09":
        //Removes extra 0 and adds am
        time = time.replace(/0/, "") + " am";
        break;
    case "10":
    case "11":
        //Adds am
        time += " am";
        break;
    case "12":
        //Adds pm
        time += " pm";
        break;
    case "13":
        //Replaces 13 with 1 and adds pm
        time = time.replace(/13/, "1") + " pm"
    case "14":
        //Replaces 14 with 2 and adds pm
        time = time.replace(/14/, "2") + " pm";
        break;
    case "15":
        //Replaces 15 with 3 and adds pm
        time = time.replace(/15/, "3") + " pm";
        break;
    case "16":
        //Replaces 16 with 4 and adds pm
        time = time.replace(/16/, "4") + " pm";
        break;
    case "17":
        //Replaces 17 with 5 and adds pm
        time = time.replace(/17/, "5") + " pm";
        break;
    case "18":
        //Replaces 18 with 6 and adds pm
        time = time.replace(/18/, "6") + " pm";
        break;
    case "19":
        //Replaces 19 with 7 and adds pm
        time = time.replace(/19/, "7") + " pm";
        break;
    case "20":
        //Replaces 20 with 8 and adds pm
        time = time.replace(/20/, "8") + " pm";
        break;
    case "21":
        //Replaces 21 with 9 and adds pm
        time = time.replace(/21/, "9") + " pm";
        break;
    case "22":
        //Replaces 22 with 10 and adds pm
        time = time.replace(/22/, "10") + " pm";
        break;
    case "23":
        //Replaces 23 with 11 and adds pm
        time = time.replace(/23/, "11") + " pm";
        break;
    }
    //Uses only a portion of the string to accommodate possible future
    //numbers
    if (emId.substring(0,4) === "time") {
        //Sets text in header to time
    $("#" + emId + " .ui-btn-text").html(time);
    } else {
        //For displaying all of the logs
    $("#" + emId).append(time + "<br>");
    }
});
}
```

Comment: You need to show the code for `getLogTime()` and `getLogData()`.

Comment: @j08691 Added an example of how my JSON is formatted for you.

Comment: @Alwaysdeadfred Going to need more than just a single entry

Comment: @KyleMacey Added another line of JSON for you. It's all formatted the same way.

Comment: @Juhana Added `getLogTime` for you, but I don't think giving you `getLogData` would be much help. It accesses the JSON and appends it to the paragraph in the same way that `getLogTime` does and the formatting is useless for the JSON data I gave. That was mostly given to show how the JSON file is structured.

Comment: On the contrary, it has everything to do with the problem! See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you get more data with `$.getJSON()`, you're using AJAX which is *asynchronous*. That means that the script doesn't stop to wait for the call to finish but continues the execution. Since there's a delay while the data is being retrieved from the server but the dividers are printed immediately, the data is always printed after the dividers.

An easy fix is to reserve containers for the data in the main loop so that it doesn't matter when the AJAX calls are finished.

```
function getAllLogs(emId) {
    $.getJSON('datafile.json', function(data) {

        var $emId = $( '#' + emId );  // cache the main container

        $("#" + emId).html("All logs:<br>");
        var firstDateDisplayed = false;
        $.each(data, function(index, value) {
            //Only displays dates once, then all log sheets for that date
            if (firstDateDisplayed === false ||
                data[index-1].log_sheet.time !== value.log_sheet.time) {

                $emId.append("<br>----------------<br>");

                // create a container for the date and have getLogDate() fill it later
                $emId.append( '<div id="'+emId+'Date'+index+'"></div>' );
                getLogDate(emId+'Date'+index, index);

                firstDateDisplayed = true;
            }

            // do the same to the rest of the functions as we did above for getLogDate()
            $emId.append( '<div id="'+emId+'Time'+index+'"></div>' );
            $emId.append( '<div id="'+emId+'Data'+index+'"></div>' );
            getLogTime(emId+'Time'+index, index);
            getLogData(emId+'Data'+index, index);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Great explanation, but to make this work I'd have to change my get functions and I don't think it's worth it for this small of a change.

Answer (score 1):

So basicly what you wanna do is type out the ---- when there is a new date apperance?

```
var json = [
{
    "log_sheet": {
        "data":"4",
        "date":"2012-07-27T00:00:00-06:00",
        "time":"2000-01-01T02:15:00Z",
        "more_data":"7"
    }
},
{
    "log_sheet": {
        "data":"4",
        "date":"2012-07-27T00:00:00-06:00",
        "time":"2000-01-01T02:15:00Z",
        "more_data":"7"
    }
},
{
    "log_sheet": {
        "data":"4",
        "date":"2012-07-27T00:00:00-06:00",
        "time":"2000-01-01T02:15:00Z",
        "more_data":"7"
    }
},
{
    "log_sheet": {
        "data":"4",
        "date":"2012-07-27T00:00:00-06:00",
        "time":"2000-01-01T02:17:00Z",
        "more_data":"7"
    }
}
];


console.log("All logs:");
$.each(json, function(index, value) {
  if(index == 0 || (index > 0 && json[index-1].log_sheet.time !== value.log_sheet.time))
  {
   console.log("-----------");
  }
  console.log("Date " + index + ": " + value.log_sheet.date);
  console.log("Time " + index + ": " + value.log_sheet.time);
  console.log("Data " + index + ": " + value.log_sheet.data);
});
```

Result:

```
All logs:
-----------
Date 0: 2012-07-27T00:00:00-06:00
Time 0: 2000-01-01T02:15:00Z
Data 0: 4
Date 1: 2012-07-27T00:00:00-06:00
Time 1: 2000-01-01T02:15:00Z
Data 1: 4
Date 2: 2012-07-27T00:00:00-06:00
Time 2: 2000-01-01T02:15:00Z
Data 2: 4
-----------
Date 3: 2012-07-27T00:00:00-06:00
Time 3: 2000-01-01T02:17:00Z
Data 3: 4
```

So your function rewritten would look like this:

```
function getAllLogs(emId) {
    $.getJSON('datafile.json', function(data) {
        var $output = $("#" + emId);
        $output.html("All logs:<br>");
        $.each(data, function(index, value) {
            //Only displays dates once, then all log sheets for that date
            if(index == 0 || (index > 0 && json[index-1].log_sheet.time !== value.log_sheet.time))
            {
                $output.append("<br>----------------<br>");
                //Formats and appends date to a paragraph
                //getLogDate(emId, index);
                $output.append("Date " + index + ": " + value.log_sheet.time +"<br/>");
            }
            //Formats and appends time to a paragraph
            //getLogTime(emId, index);
            $output.append("Time " + index + ": " + value.log_sheet.time +"<br/>");
            //Formats and appends all data to a paragraph
            //getLogData(emId, index);
            $output.append("Data " + index + ": " + value.log_sheet.data +"<br/>");
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: This is essentially what I want, except I only want each date to display once. The --- is to provide a distinction between the different date sections.

Comment: Also console.log won't output to the window I want it to.

Comment: Edited with your function rewritten.

Comment: I like `var $output = $("#" + emId);`. It makes the code look a lot better and I've added it to my version, but this still doesn't fix my problem. Removing calls to the other functions leaves the data in a confusing format(what the `----------------` was trying to help with) and rewriting the functions so that they return a value to be appended, instead of appending in the function, would break other points in the code where they are called.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather from your post, you're essentially grouping logs of `data` and `time` by their `date` property. If that's the cast, you could try something like this:

```
function getAllLogs(elementId)
{
    $.getJSON('datafile.json', function(data)
    {
        var logElement = $('#' + elementId).append('All logs:<br />');

        var lastLogDateDisplayed = null;
        $.each(data, function(index, value)
        {
            // check if we've reached another date
            if (lastLogDateDisplayed != value.log_sheet.date)
            {
                // update the last shown date, and select its html
                lastLogDateDisplayed = value.log_sheet.date;
                logElement.append('----------------<br />');
                    .append(getLogDate(value));
            }

            // select the time and data as html strings
            logElement.append(getLogTime(value))
                .append(getLogData(value));
        });
    });
}
```

There's a few improvements here worth noting explicitliy. Firstly we're only selecting the `elementId` element once. This improves performance on our selectors from a previous hit rate of `1 + 4n` down to `1`. Additionally, as a result of this, the `getLogDate`, `getLogTime` and `getLogData` are not accepting the `value` (i.e. the current log item), and are returning either a dom, or jQuery object to append to the log element itself.

It's a few alterations, but it's cleaner, and hopefully will help solve your problem.

Comment: I have changed my if statement to be closer to yours as yours is cleaner, however I haven't changed anything else as all three get functions are called elsewhere and I would have to make changes to them. Also I fail to see how this solves my problem. As far as I can tell your code only prints `----------------` once before the JSON is used, instead of being printed before every new date. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I've updated my answer so that the dashes are in the correct place; I'd consider maybe making this a CSS style thing instead as it would be neater. :)

Comment: As I said before I can't really change my get functions to fit what your code has so I can't truly test your code. I've done my best to make my code fit yours while keeping my functions the same, but it still prints both lines of dashes at the top. As for CSS I have two files totaling about 600 lines as well as a call to the jQuery mobile style sheet and I don't know any CSS and don't want to mess with them for something this small.